# termVectors vs omitTermFreqAndPosition in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have confusion in understanding termVectors and omitTermFreqAndPosition field properties.

What I understood is:

If omitTermFreqAndPosition is set to false then solr will store the frequency and position of every term and this information will be used to sort the documents by default.

If termVectors is set to true then we will we able to retrieve the frequency and position information. termVector is not responsible for storing rather just enables us to explicitly see those information.

If omitTermFreqAndPosition and termVectors both set to true then we will not be able to retrieve the frequency information as omitTermFreqAndPosition will make solr ignore those information.

Please tell me If I understood it correct.

Thanks

Comment: This question is not "opinion-based" at all. Please people, if you don't understand what the question is about, then simply **don't do anything about it**, move on.